# Invalid operants to binary ^

Tags: c++, c, compilation, ide

I'm building a function in C and facing a problem.

I know that all operands should be in the same format.

If a,b,c are integers, end result and d are floats and e=2.71828, how to make the program run?

```
f=(a*(e^(-((x-b)^2/(2*c^2))))+d);
```

Comment: `^` is a binary xor, not exponentiation. See the `exp()` function.

Answer (score 2):

`^` is the bitwise exclusive-or operator, and only works on integer types.

I'm guessing you want exponentiation. There's no operator for that, but the standard library contains exponentiation functions: `pow` for arbitrary values, and `exp` for `e`. For squaring, it's probably better to use multiplication.

The question's tagged with two different languages, which have different standard libraries. In C, you'd do

```
#include <math.h>

f = a*exp((x-b)*(x-b)/(2*c*c)) + d;
```

In C++, the header is `<cmath>`, and the functions are in the `std` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Use pow instead of ^ operator in c++. Include cmath preprocessor at the top